# How can I write Unit Test for persist and flush exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, persistence

I have the following code:

```
try {
  em.persist(myObject);
  em.flush();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("An Exception occur when trying to persist and flush");
}
```

In test I have mock my EntityManager with Mockito:

```
    @Mock
EntityManager mockEm;
```

but as persist and flush are void methods, I'm not able able to write something like:

```
when(mockEm.persist(anObject).then(doSomeThing);
```

How can I write unit testing (with JUnit)to mock em.persist and em.flush in order to test both cases with and without exception?
Thanks.

Comment: This answer can't simply be answered. What exactly do you want to test - what happens **inside** `persist() / flush()` - or are you only interested to verify that these two methods are invoked on the `em` object?

Comment: I want to test when persist or flush return an exception like EntityExistException or PersistenceException. In that case my code will catch the Exception and I want to test that code really catch and execute the corresponding code.

Comment: Then you probably want to *mock* that em object and have it throw an exception upon calls to these methods.

Comment: Yes exactly. Who can I do?

Comment: First of all you want to update your question to add that piece of information there. **Seriously** update your question. Instead of giving random responses in comments and ignoring the feedback you already received.

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning how to use and communicate with Stackoverflow. I have updated my question. Is it better understandable?

Comment: Thing is: you already showed some code (attached to the answer from Pijotrek) that uses Mockito annotations. So it is not all clear what exactly prevents you from using Mockito for this simple piece of code. Any Mockito tutorial would show the few steps required to create a mock and how to spec the few, simple method calls that your production code is making. In that sense: in your update your mainly repeating what you already said. Instead. show us the test you wrote, and tell us why exactly you are stuck with Mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we need more details. For now, you can do something like this: (it's kind of pseudo-code).

```
@Test // it passess when there's one object in repository (I assume u have clean memory db)
public void shouldPersistMyObject() throws Exception {
    em.persist(myObject);
    em.flush();
    Assert.assertThat(dao.findAll(), Matchers.equalTo(1));
}

@Test(expected = <YourDesiredException>.class) // if <YourDesiredException> is thrown, your test passes
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenSavingCorruptedData() {
    //set NULL on some @NotNull value, then save, like:
    myObject.setUserId(null);
    em.save(myObject); //exception is thrown
}
```

Comment: Usually I wrote my test like : 
'@Mock
EntityManager mockEm;
@Test
public void myTest() {
when

Comment: Sorry poor use of comment.
I try again:
Usually I wrote my test like:
`@Mock 
EntityManager mockEm;
@Mock
Query mockQuery;   
@InjectMocks
MyClassToTest myClassToTest;
when(mockEm.createNamedQuery("MyObject.findById"))
                .thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.setParameter(MyClassToTest.PARAM_ID, EXISTING_ID))
                .thenReturn(mockQuery);
@Test
public void testFindById() throws Exception {
when(mockQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(existingObject);
MyObject result=myClassToTest.findById(mockEmf, EXISTING_ID);
assertEquals(existingObject, result);
}`

Comment: Dont put such information into comments - update your question instead. Or can you read what you just put up there?